# Call from module.export ; a function that is inside the same module.export

Tags: node.js

I need help about this piece of code.
What i am trying to do, is to call a function in the "root" of a module.export. But the call provide from a function inside the same module.export. Here is what I got :

From another script, I have the function "base-execute" called. 
What i'm trying to do, is to call the function "Tocall-Function" just after. Is this possible ?

```
module.exports.main = {

   Part1 : {
      Sub1 : {
         base-execute(){
           // Some code and then call the "Tocall-Function" //
         }
      },
      Sub2 : {...}
   },
  Part2 : {...}


  Tocall-Function(){
    //Another piece of code//
  }

}
```

I tried 'this.Tocall-Function'. But the 'this' itself return only what is written right before the "base-execute" function (what is inside the Sub1 part).

I can access variables that are not inside the module.exports.main. But I can't call it itself.

I can't find something working in my case. If someone can help me out that will be great !

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Can you include the code where you use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `main` separately from export, and call the function you want to call with `main.TocallFunction();`

```
const main = {

  Part1 : {
    Sub1 : {
      baseExecute() {
        main.TocallFunction();
        // Some code and then call the "Tocall-Function" //
      }
    },
    Sub2 : {}
  },
  Part2 : {},
  TocallFunction() {
    //Another piece of code//
  }
};

exports.main = main;
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy workaround is to create a reference to your export object from within the script.

```
var main = {

   Part1 : {
      Sub1 : {
         base-execute(){
           // Some code and then call the "Tocall-Function" //

           main.Tocall_Function()
         }
      },
      Sub2 : {...}
   },
  Part2 : {...}


  Tocall_Function(){
    //Another piece of code//
  }

} 


module.exports.main = main;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
    const toCallFunction = () => console.log("To Call Function");

    module.exports = { toCallFunction: toCallFunction, main: { part1: { sub1: () => toCallFunction  }} };
```

Then you can import your module like this:

```
    const { main, toCallFunction } = require("./myCustomModule")
```